# second order ordinary differential equation with periodic coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

thanks in advance. This is my first time here, so if my question is not clear , pls let me know in the comments. I am trying to solve this differential equation subject to the periodic boundary condition ($\psi[\phi]=\psi[\phi+2 \pi]$). The parameters of the equation are $\eta_m$, $\eta_p$ and $\Phi$. Also  $E$ is  the energy and $\psi[\phi]$ is the wave function. I am actually more interested in finding out $E$ in terms of the paramters than the wave function itself. This is the equation (I have also included Mathematica codes at the end, in case you need to use it).

$ \left(\text{$\eta_m$}^2 (\Phi +3) \Phi  \left(-e^{3 i \phi }\right)-2 e^{i \phi } \left(2 E^2-\Phi  (\Phi +1) (\text{$\eta_m$} \text{$\eta _p$}-2)\right)-4 E\ \text{$\eta_m$} (\Phi +1) e^{2 i \phi }-\text{$\eta _p$}^2 (\Phi -1) \Phi  e^{-i \phi }+4  \text{$\eta _p$} \Phi \right) \psi (\phi )-i  \left(\text{$\eta_m$}^2 (2 \Phi +3) \left(-e^{3 i \phi }\right)+2 (2 \Phi +1) e^{i \phi } (\text{$\eta_m$} \text{$\eta _p$}-2)-4 E\ \text{$\eta_m$} e^{2 i \phi }+\text{$\eta _p$}^2 (1-2 \Phi ) e^{-i \phi }+4 E \ \text{$\eta _p$}\right)\psi '(\phi )+\left(\text{$\eta_m$}^2 e^{3 i \phi }-2 e^{i \phi } (\text{$\eta_m$} \text{$\eta _p$}-2)+\text{$\eta _p$}^2 e^{-i \phi }\right)\psi ''(\phi ) $

The parameters can be large and small, so perturbation theory wont work for the general case.
Here is what I have tried so far.

1. Mathematica cant solve this.
2. I have tried the series $\psi[\phi]=\Sigma_{n=-\infty}^{n=+\infty}  c_n e^{-i n \phi} $, and this is the recursion relation I get

$2  \left(2 \text{E}^2-(\text{$\eta_m$} \text{$\eta_p$}-2) (n+\Phi ) (n+\Phi +1)\right)c_{n-1}+4 \text{E} \text{$\eta_m$}  (n+\Phi +1) c_{n-2} +\text{$\eta_m$}^2  (n+\Phi ) (n+\Phi +3)c_{n-3}+\text{$\eta_p$}^2  (n+\Phi -1) (n+\Phi ) c_{n+1}=4 \text{E} \  \text{$\eta_p$}  (n+\Phi ) c_{n}$

I dont know what to do with this . How can I determine the coefficients $c_n$? There are five different $c_n$ terms.

3. I have fourier transformed this equation, but I get sth similar to the above recursion relation.
4. If I do the transformation $z=e^{i \phi}$, $\partial_{\phi}=i z \partial_z$, mathematica can solve this in terms of holonomic functions, but I am not sure whether this transformation is correct or not, since z is a complex variable.

Any suggestions or hints as to how to solve this or what approach to use would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the Mathematica code for the equation and recursion(Et is the energy, since E is predefined in Mathematica)

ψ
[
ϕ
]

⁢

(


-

(

2
⁢

ⅇ

ⅈ
⁢
ϕ


⁢

(


2
⁢

Et
2


-

Φ
⁢

(

Φ
+
1

)

⁢

(


ηm
⁢
ηp

-
2

)



)


)


-

4
⁢
Et
⁢
ηm
⁢

(

Φ
+
1

)

⁢

ⅇ

2
⁢
ⅈ
⁢
ϕ



+

4
⁢
Et
⁢
ηp
⁢
Φ

+


ηm
2

⁢

(

Φ
+
3

)

⁢
Φ
⁢

(

-

ⅇ

3
⁢
ⅈ
⁢
ϕ



)


-


ηp
2

⁢

(

Φ
-
1

)

⁢
Φ
⁢

ⅇ


-
ⅈ

⁢
ϕ




)


-

ⅈ
⁢


ψ
′

[
ϕ
]

⁢

(



-
4

⁢
Et
⁢
ηm
⁢

ⅇ

2
⁢
ⅈ
⁢
ϕ



+

4
⁢
ⅇ
⁢
ηp

+


ηm
2

⁢

(


2
⁢
Φ

+
3

)

⁢

(

-

ⅇ

3
⁢
ⅈ
⁢
ϕ



)


+

2
⁢

(


2
⁢
Φ

+
1

)

⁢

ⅇ

ⅈ
⁢
ϕ


⁢

(


ηm
⁢
ηp

-
2

)


+


ηp
2

⁢

(

1
-

2
⁢
Φ


)

⁢

ⅇ


-
ⅈ

⁢
ϕ




)


+



ψ
′′

[
ϕ
]

⁢

(



ηm
2

⁢

ⅇ

3
⁢
ⅈ
⁢
ϕ



-

2
⁢

ⅇ

ⅈ
⁢
ϕ


⁢

(


ηm
⁢
ηp

-
2

)


+


ηp
2

⁢

ⅇ


-
ⅈ

⁢
ϕ




)

ηm
2

⁢

(

n
+
Φ

)

⁢

(

3
+
n
+
Φ

)

⁢

c
[


-
3

+
n

]


+

4
⁢
Et
⁢
ηm
⁢

(

1
+
n
+
Φ

)

⁢

c
[


-
2

+
n

]


+

2
⁢

(


2
⁢

Et
2


-


(


-
2

+

ηm
⁢
ηp


)

⁢

(

n
+
Φ

)

⁢

(

1
+
n
+
Φ

)



)

⁢

c
[


-
1

+
n

]


+


ηp
2

⁢

(


-
1

+
n
+
Φ

)

⁢

(

n
+
Φ

)

⁢

c
[

1
+
n

]



⩵

4
⁢
Et
⁢
ηp
⁢

(

n
+
Φ

)

⁢

c
[
n
]

Thanks again everyone, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do I miss something when stating that the structure of the equation is $a(e^{i\phi})\psi''(\phi)+b(e^{i\phi})\psi'(\phi)+c(e^{i\phi})\psi(\phi)=0$, with the coefficients Laurent polynomials in their arguments? ((Could you clean up $ηmηp$ and similar to $η_mη_p$?)) // There exist greatly reduced cases of such equations like the Mathieu equation, and these already have a large solution theory. It is not to be expected that the more general case has a simpler structure.

Comment: yes the structure is as you said and I will clean up the notation and will take look at mathieu-like equations, thanks a lot. For some cases like when(eta_m=eta_p=1, actually an important special case),  there are solutions in terms of hypergeometric functions),  I can also solve this for small eta_m and eta_p. If I use the transformation in part 4 of the question,  it will be solvable,  but I am not sure about taking the complex derivative.

Comment: I think I have found the solution to this, any equation with periodic coefficients can be put into Hill's equations. for details see.http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/ss1/bloch/hill.php

Comment: That site describes the Floquet theory for this 2D system, the basis solution that are necessary are also just obtained numerically for the general case. What you get in theory for Hill equations are the Hill matrices that allow for a more systematic perturbation expansion

Comment: you are right, putting the equation in the Hill's form doesn't guarantee an analytic solution, I just got excited for a minute by reading the title. Nevertheless, I will try putting it in the Hill's form and see if Mathematica can solve.

Comment: Generally, Mathematica is very good in applying transformation tricks to DE and integrals. So if a valid trick exists, Mathematica would most likely have applied it to the original problem. So yes, try it out, but do not expect miracles.

Answer (score 0):

Attached a short MATHEMATICA script with the purpose to obtain the series coefficient $c_k$. Some additional changes were necessary when choosing the initial conditions $(c_{-1},c_1)$. A sample with $n=10$ is handled as follows.

$$
\psi(\phi) = \sum_{k=-n}^{k=n}c_ke^{-ik\phi}
$$

```
Clear[psi]
n = 10;

ode = (etam^2 (Phi + 3) Phi (-Exp[3 I phi]) - 
  2 Exp[I phi] (2 e^2 - Phi (Phi + 1) (etam etap - 2)) - 
  4 e etam (Phi + 1) Exp[2 I phi] - 
  etap^2 (Phi - 1) Phi Exp[-I phi] + 4 etap Phi) psi[phi] - 
I (etam^2 (2 Phi + 3) (-Exp[3 I phi]) + 
  2 (2 Phi + 1) Exp[I phi] (etam etap - 2) - 
  4 e etam Exp[2 I phi] + etap^2 (1 - 2 Phi) Exp[-I phi] + 
  4 e etap) D[psi[phi], 
 phi] + (etam^2 Exp[3 I phi] - 2 Exp[I phi] (etam etap - 2) + 
  etap^2 Exp[-I phi]) D[psi[phi], phi, phi];

ODE = ode /. {phi -> \[Phi], psi -> \[Psi], 
etam -> Subscript[\[Eta], x] - I Subscript[\[Eta], y], 
etap -> Subscript[\[Eta], x] + I Subscript[\[Eta], y], 
Phi -> \[CapitalPhi], e -> \[Epsilon] I R/v}


\[Psi][x_] := Sum[c[k] Exp[I k \[Phi]], {k, -n, n}]
subs = Table[Exp[-I k \[Phi]] -> x^-k, {k, -n, n}];
res = x^(n + 1) ODE /. subs;
equs = CoefficientList[res, x];
coefs = Flatten[Table[{c[k], c[-k]}, {k, 2, n}]];
coefs[[17]] = c[0];
Length[coefs]
ne = Length[equs]
ne0 = 4;
equs0 = Take[equs, {ne0, ne - ne0}];
Length[equs0]

Solve[equs0 == 0, coefs]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cesareo, I really really appreciate all the time you put into this. I am currently trying to execute all code lines to know all the details.   One thing I noticed was that the script calculates all the $c_{k}$ coefficients in terms $c_{1}$,  $c_{-1}$, $c_{2}$, and $c_{-2}$, but in this way the solution will have four unidentified constants. Shouldn't a 2nd ODE have like two? The periodic bc is already built into the series, so I don't know how else I can omit the extra coefficients.

Comment: The ODE is complex so it needs four conditions: two for the real part and two for the imaginary. Note that the $c_k$ are real.

Comment: Don't we get like two complex constants (so four constants) for the complex ODE's? (btw, $\phi$ is a real variable here) so you are saying that $c_{k}$'s are real here? can we assume they are real?

Comment: Sorry , you already answered my question in your comment. I just didn't see it. $c_{k}$'s are real. but  If we assume they are real, we will get inconsistent answers, because $\eta_{m}=\eta_{x}- i \eta_{y}$, $\eta_{p}=\eta_{x}+ i \eta_{y}$ are complex-valued constants. for example $c_{3}$ would  be complex.

Comment: Well. About $\eta_m,\eta_p$ things can change. I assumed they were real but the formulation is the same. I will introduce those changes ASAP.

Comment: Again thanks a million, just to be completely transparent, $\phi $ is real and  $E$ is complex ($E= \epsilon \frac{i R}{v}$ in which $R$, $v$ and $\epsilon$ are real)

Comment: Now the script is adapted to handle the modifications, with four conditions assumed with two undefined complex constants $(c_{-1},c_1)$. I hope this helps.

Comment: Again thank you so much, not only did it help, but it also gave me some insights and ideas. The community at the stackexchange is really great.  Thanks